# unable to update JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a method in MediaLibrary.java as follows

```
private void playListActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    mediaLibraryDTO dto=new mediaLibraryDTO();
    dto.setSongList(currentSongField.getText());
    new Dashboard().libraryList(dto);
}
```

Similarly I have MediaLibraryDTO.java as follows

```
public class mediaLibraryDTO {
    private String songList;

    public String getSongList() {
        return songList;
    }

    public void setSongList(String songList) {
        this.songList = songList;
    }

}
```

Similarly i have a method in Dashboard.java as follows

```
public void libraryList(mediaLibraryDTO dto) {
    File file = new File(dto.getSongList());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, file);
    JList list = new JList(model);
    model.addElement(file.toString());
    playList.setModel(model);
}
```

Comment: ...and the error you're seeing is...?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: what's your actual question? what your log says?